# How do I integrate mobile initiated video call with web based [node.js] video call?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, socket.io, webrtc

I need to video call from mobile [android / ios] to someone over web [video call] using node.js and 3rd party api which supports this feature? I don't have much idea about all this. A kind explanation is needed please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge i would like to suggest as below.

- Using node.js you can manage your socket, which keeps broadcast which user is online / offline.
- Using any 3rd party WebRTC like [Vidyo](http://www.vidyo.com/), [google](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/) , [hangout](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/) API or [others](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=WEBRTC%20provider%20&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ID7uV7bLEcr08we69IDwBA#q=webrtc%20providers) .
- Using WebRTC protocol at your own server, you can also develop your own WebRTC channel.

https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios
https://github.com/GleasonK/android-webrtc-tutorial

Socket can work as separate service in Android, but in Android socket connection will go off if you go background or kill app. in this situation you have to get video call data using Push kit ( Silent push notification.

Let me know if you need anymore information for setting up such architecture.

Comment: i need to send video message if user/client is offline. Is it possible ? And if yes where would be storing that messages untill is downloaded by user/client

Comment: Video message is different thing. you can record / get from gallery , convert it to base64 string, then upload it to serve using API. getting video from server then you can make absolute URL and get it to application using API.